# A phrase about "my brain" and "programming"

Tags: expressions, headlinese

I want to add some text about programming in relation to my brain, above a picture, and would like to know if any of the below phrases are correct:

> My brain, while programming.
>
> My brain, during programming.
>
> My brain, while I'm programming.
>
> How my brain feels during programming.

Please check this image: [http://imgur.com/EAgtQC7](https://imgur.com/EAgtQC7)

Could anyone please explain which one would be most fitting and why?

Comment: The [wikipedia page for the US anti-drug campaign "This is your brain on drugs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Your_Brain_on_Drugs) might be helpful.

Comment: The link to your image is **broken**!

Comment: The result: https://instagram.fotp1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/14714486_1110585928977706_7470997179331510272_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIwNjYxMDg3Mzc3ODQ5NzQ4Mg%3D%3D.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky because programming is like riding: it can be a noun as in "I like horse riding" and also an active participle "I went riding today".

While is a conjunction so it needs a clause after it: during is a  preposition which needs a noun after it. The ones with 'while' work because the active participle meaning is what you intended, but the ones with 'during' don't, because the noun meaning of programming isn't what you meant.

"My brain during programming" sounds like your brain is being programmed.

As for the image (maaaaaaaan that's a slow web site!), I agree with John Clifford: the caption should be "my brain.... while programming", laid out as he suggested. Eliminate the two 'during' options as explained above, and go for the shortest. As they say, brevity is the soul of wit.

Comment: If it weren't for the fact that the joke would go over most people's heads, I would suggest "This is my brain on programming".

Comment: I edited my question.  Please check the image.

Comment: For a meme image like that, it would probably be best to have the top line as "MY BRAIN" and the bottom line as "WHILE PROGRAMMING". In that kind of image, the grammatical constructs aren't so important.